# Can I have a multi-process global variable?

Tags: android, variables, process, static, global

I have a real problem using my app that involve 2 processes. One process its executing a Service (p1) and the other the GUI (p2).

I have a class in p2 that implements the use of an object (iThing) that is custom memory managed (and its static). It has to be like this bacause of Android OS implementation of destroying the views whenever he wants.

```
public class Connections{
    public static int iGlobalCounter=0;
    public static Object iThing;

    public static void start(){
        iGlobalCounter++;
        Log.d("PROCESS", "UP: "+iGlobalCounter);
        if (iGlobalCounter<=1){
            //Create the object "iThing"
        }
    }

    public static int stop(){
        iGlobalCounter--;
        Log.d("PROCESS", "DOWN: "+iGlobalCounter);
        if (iGlobalCounter<=0){
            //Destroy the object "iThing"
        }
    }

}
```

The main GUI (in p2), starts and stops the variable on the onCreate / onDestroy (for all views in my app)

```
public class MyMainClass extends Activity{
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        Connections.start();
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy(){
        super.onDestroy();
        Connections.stop();
    }

}
```

Finally in p1 I have the service, which also needs the variable, so, it does the same

```
public class MyMainService extends Service{
    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        Connections.start();
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy(){
        super.onDestroy();
        Connections.stop();
    }

}
```

The problem is that if I use only p2 (GUI), it goes all well, but when I execute the service (in p1), the counter doesn't increment from the last state, but from 0, resulting in destroying the object when leaving the service, not the app.

if do this navigation, I get the following counters:
MyMainClass (1) --> OtherClass (2) --> AnotherClass (3) --> **MyMainService** (**1**)

My question is if there is a way of having a multi-process global variable? As it seems that every process takes its own static variables and are not "real static". A solution could be using SharedPreferences to save the state, but not really nice solution, as it hasn't to be saved when leaving the app.

Thanks,
PAU

Answer (score 1):

I think that you should extend `Application` class and put your `globalVariable` there.

Comment: Sorry, I just tried this but keeps happening the same: two processes, to instances

Comment: Maybe in this case we see an example of concurrency. Make your GlobalVariable in the Application class static and write a synchronized updater of it.

Answer (score 0):

You can store your global data in shared memory (see [MemoryFile](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/MemoryFile.html)).
To synchronize access to the file, I think the best approach is to implement some sort of spinlock using the same memory file.
In and case, I don't know a simply way of doing this.

Answer (score 0):

You have the following options which you can look into for sharing data between different processes,

Message Queue,

Named Pipes,

Memory mapped files

WCF on Named Pipes or MSMQ